# How to create new toplevel window with treeview object?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, treeview, toplevel

i cant figure out why this code is not working. I am trying to make a treeview in new Toplevel window after clicking on a Button. But when i add a scrollbar to treeview - treeview disappear (I comment the part wih scrollbar). Here is code:

```
from tkinter import*
class Treeview(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title('Contacts List')
        self.geometry('1050x527')
        columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5')
        self = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show='headings')
        self.heading('#1', text='Name')
        self.heading('#2', text='Birthday')
        self.heading('#3', text='Email')
        self.heading('#4', text='Number')
        self.heading('#5', text='Notes')
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        #scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.yview)
        #self.configure(yscroll=scrollbar.set)
        #scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
    root = Tk()
    def tree():
        new= Treeview(root)
    button7 = ttk.Button(root,text="Contacts", command=tree)
    button7.grid(row=1,column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You seem to have indentation problems in the code. You define `root` inside `__init__`.

Comment: Also, you never actually grid the new Treeview. Have you tried using `new.grid` to grid the new Treeview? You change `self` from a `Toplevel` into a `Treeview` as well, which you definitely should not be doing. Instead of changing `self` to a `Treeview`, make a variable for it, something like `self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(...`.

Comment: Ok but how can i fix it? Or maybe how can i create Toplevel window with different way?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by redefining `self`?

Comment: I dont know i am new to tkinter and treeview.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I dont understand can you please rewrite my code? Because i have no idea about what are you talking about:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redefining `self` to be the `ttk.Treeview` instance. Later, when you create the scrollbar, this cause the scrollbar to be a child of the `ttk.Treeview` widget.

You should definitely not be redefining `self`. Use a different variable, such as `tree`. Or better, use `self.tree` so that you can reference the tree from other methods.

```
class Treeview(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title('Contacts List')
        self.geometry('1050x527')
        columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=columns, show='headings')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='Name')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Birthday')
        self.tree.heading('#3', text='Email')
        self.tree.heading('#4', text='Number')
        self.tree.heading('#5', text='Notes')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
```

Comment: ok thanks and is it good way to create the treeview like i did? Or there are better ways?

Comment: @GGGGGG Well, wildcard imports are discouraged (so try to avoid using `from tkinter import *` if you can). If you want to reference the treeview elsewhere in the class, I suggest using `self.treeview` instead of simply `treeview`. This enables you to use the treeview in any method of the class.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin do you mean using self.treeview instead of tree? Because treeview is not a variable in his solution.

Comment: @GGGGGG My mistake. Same principle still applies, though: you can use `self.tree` instead of `tree`. Using `self.` ensures that the variable can be used throughout the class

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the example to use `self.tree` rather than `tree`.